# What don't I understand about passing a pointer as a parameter?

Tags: c++

I made the following tidbit of code to move the zeros to the front of an array (By the way, is there a more elegant and efficient procedure?). For some reason, when I test the function, it doesn't modify the array, like it should be doing. I can't figure out what's going wrong.

```
void zeros_to_front(int* arr, int sz) { 
    std::vector<int> nonzeroesVec;
    for (int k = 0; k < sz; ++k) { 
        if (arr[k] != 0) 
            nonzeroesVec.push_back(arr[k]);
    }
    int numzeroes = sz - nonzeroesVec.size();
    int j(0), k(0);
    while (j < numzeroes) 
        arr[j++] = 0;
    while (j < sz)
        arr[j++] = nonzeroesVec[k++];
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the symptom is, I can't seem to reproduce it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

void zeros_to_front(int* arr, int sz) { 
    std::vector<int> nonzeroesVec;
    for (int k = 0; k < sz; ++k) { 
        if (arr[k] != 0) 
            nonzeroesVec.push_back(arr[k]);
    }
    int numzeroes = sz - nonzeroesVec.size();
    int j(0), k(0);
    while (j < numzeroes) 
        arr[j++] = 0;
    while (j < sz)
        arr[j++] = nonzeroesVec[k++];
}   

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int ptr[5] = {0};
    ptr[0] = 1;
    zeros_to_front(ptr,5);
    for (int i = 0;i < 5;++i){
        printf("%d",ptr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

works as expected and prints out "00001".

Comment: Nevermind ... Dumb error ... I figured out what I did. :(

Comment: @user2967799: failed to allocate `sz` elements before calling the function?

Answer (score 2):

**If you don't care about the order of the non-zero elements afterward, you can use this:**

```
void swap(int& x, int& y)
{
    x ^= y;
    y ^= x;
    x ^= y;
}    

void zerosToFront(int arr[], int size)
{
    if(size < 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    int front = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == 0)
        {
            swap(arr[i], arr[front++]);
        }
    }
}
```

It iterates once through the array, and whenever it finds a zero, it swaps that zero to the front of the array. It's `O(n)`, which is as efficient as you can get.

**However, if you *do* care about order, you can use**:

```
void zerosToFront(int arr[], int size)
{
    if(size < 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == 0)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                swap(arr[i - j], arr[i - j- 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This iterates through the array once, and whenever it finds a zero, the inner for loop essentially shifts everything before the zero we found over to the right to make room for the zero at the beginning of the list. However, this is `O(n^2)` due to the inner for loop, hence less efficient. For relatively small arrays you won't notice the performance difference, though.

**Edit:
Actually, I just realized something interesting. If you traverse the array backwards, you can push the zeros to the front and retain the ordering of the non-zero elements in O(n) time.**

```
void ztf(int arr[], int size)
{
    if(size < 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    int back = size - 1;
    for(int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(arr[i] != 0)
        {
            arr[back--] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    while(back >= 0)
    {
        arr[back--] = 0;
    }
}
```

Just thought that was nifty.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

void
shake(int * arr, std::size_t N)
{
    bool changed;
    do
    {
        changed = false;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N - 1; ++i)
        {
            if (arr[i + 1] == 0 && arr[i] != 0)
            {
                std::swap(arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
                changed = true;                
            }
        }
    }
    while (changed);
}

int
main ()
{
    std::vector<int> vec { 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0 };
    shake(&vec[0], vec.size());
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
}
```